# Alias for directory name with space in the name

Tags: alias

```
~$ alias Any_Name=/home/User/Desktop/Folder\ Name
~$ Any_Name
bash: /home/User/Desktop/Folder: No such file or directory
~$
```

that same bash error is shown even if double quotes is used

So how do i reach that folder using the alias command ?

```
~$ cd "$Any_Name"
~$
~$ cd $Any_Name
~$ pwd
```

/home/User

Also does not seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ...

```
cd "$Any_Name"
```

Environment variables need to be evaluated.

And also ...

```
 alias Any_Name="/home/User/Desktop/Folder\ Name"
```

---

By the way ...

```
:~$pwd
/home/rinzind
:~$ alias
alias a='cd /tmp'
:~$ a
:/tmp$ pwd
/tmp
:/tmp$
```

---

I forgot this was about spaces ...

```
:~$ cd /tmp/
:~$ mkdir "tmp 2/"
:~$ alias a="cd /tmp/tmp\ 2/"
:~$ a
:/tmp/tmp 2$
```